# New Fragment Layout not showing on screen android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying call a New "FoodMenuFragmentDetail1" fragment from a fragment but whenever i click on button its go on next fragment but not shown on screen.
what is the problem?
here code how i call fragment..
Both layouts are linearlayout

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int sss=0;
        String vvv=String.format("%03d", view.getId());
        Fragment newFragment = new FoodMenuFragmentDetail1();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("ssss", sss);
        bundle.putString("vvvv", vvv);
        newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.Foodmain,
                newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack("--");
        transaction.commit();


    }
```

oncreate function in FoodMenuFragmentDetail1

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.food_menu_fragment_detail,
            container, false);
    aq = new AQuery(getActivity(), view);
    lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.price_list);
    Foodbaricon = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fav_star);
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity(),
            ProgressDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    return view;
}
```

layout  of FoodMenuFragmentDetail1

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: do you get any log? Show your layouts and onCreate of your FoodMenuFragmentDetail1();

Comment: i just add code. no i am not using any log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i got solution.
First Fragment Layout Changed from LinearLayout to FrameLayout and then replace with Second Fragment Layout and Now its working

Answer (score 0):

You place the Fragment in the container with the id `R.id.Foodmain`, but in your layout the container has the id `layout_container`. If this is the right code change the id in your FragmentTransaction.

Comment: R.id.Foodmain id of previous fragment id and layout_container id of new Fragment which will call